# Looping through enum values without enhanced for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, enums

I am trying to go through every value of my enum list `Colors`

if I use:

```
for (AnotherClass.Colors color : AnotherClass.Colors.values()) {
     System.out.println(color);
}
```

I get the desired result. I am wondering if that is the only way to use a for loop to loop through this? I mean is there no other way to loop through this?

Comment: Firing up eclipse or whatever you use, and playing around for a while, and a little peeking at the docs should have given you what you are seeking, and should have given you well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `values()` method of an enum returns an array. If you want to iterate through an array with a normal `for` loop, it would look like this:

```
AnotherClass.Colors[] values = AnotherClass.Colors.values();
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
    System.out.println(values[i]);
}
```

Enhanced `for` loops and enums were both introduced in Java 1.5, so the enhanced `for` loop has always been the obvious way to iterate through enum values.

Comment: Thank you! I figured I would have to create another array and then iterate through it if I didnt want to use an enhanced for loop.

Comment: @AP that is not entirely true. You don't have to create another array, you can iterate through the array returned by `values()`.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ - Can I do it with a traditional for loop though? Because thats what Im doing with enhanced for loop, is iterating through array returned by values() right?

Comment: @AP It is doing virtually the same thing in both cases. It is getting an array from `values()` and iterating through it. It is not creating *another* array in either case.

Answer (score 3):

With Java 8, you can use Streams instead:

```
AnotherClass.Colors.values().forEach(color->System.out.println(color));
```

Comment: `values()` returns an array. Arrays do not have a `forEach` method.